# How to read eclipse error

Tags: eclipse

Can someone here explain how to pinpoint exactly the error in eclipse? for example like this..

```
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.localhost.one/com.localhost.one.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:112)
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:90)
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:87)
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at com.localhost.one.Main.onCreate(Main.java:80)
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  ... 11 more
```

Eclipse IDE is great for it has many plugins but it lacks a lot of what VS has. If someone can tell me how to pinpoint exactly my error or where I have my null pointer, from what variable, from what method in eclipse? Thanks. Finding the error in eclipse is very time consuming in eclipse..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you find out your package name and error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException <<<<Error
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:112)
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:90)
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:87)
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
07-07 00:46:34.968: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at com.localhost.one.Main.onCreate(Main.java:80)


Line no.80 and class name Main.java
```

Comment: OH.. SO this is my error? com.localhost.one.Main.onCreate(Main.java:80) in here?

Comment: yes that your error find your class and package name in logcat(error log)

Comment: Ok.. Thank you. One question though, do you have any known plugin for eclipse to make it like VS? Like It will highlight my error?

Comment: OK.. Thanks again.. I will accept this answer.. Im just curiuos why eclipse have to show many line. It makes no sense.. hahaha

Comment: no no...problem is android logcat ,,,dont say eclipse.Because when you develop java application it gives nice error log and short log.

Comment: Oh im sorry.. Hope android team develop a clean and nice logcat.